# Django OneToOneField with possible blank field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, one-to-one

Working with Django 1.11 and a **postgreSQL Database** (just switched from sqlite and didn't have this problem before)

So I have 3 models:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    is_parent = models.BooleanField()

class VideoGamePurchase(models.Model):
    bought_by = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    after_homework = models.OneToOneField(HomeWork, OPTIONS???)

class HomeWork(models.Model):
    done_by = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    content = models.CharField(blablaba)
```

So the logic I'm try to implement is that if `Person.is_parent` is `True` a `VideoGamePurchase` instance can be created with an empty or null field for `after_homework`. However, if `Person.is_parent` is `False`, I want this field to be the primary key of a unique `HomeWork` object.

I can't find the right options to achieve this:

If I don't have `primary_key=True` then the makemigrations fails:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to video_game_purchase without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

so I guess I hav to have `primary_key=True`. But then it seems like I can't have `null=True`or `blank=True`.

Is there a way to have a `OneToOneField` optionally empty with postgreSQL?

Is there a other/simpler way to implement this sort of logic?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want the `after_homework` field to be optional, then you should use `null=True` and `blank=True`.

```
class VideoGamePurchase(models.Model):
    bought_by = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    after_homework = models.OneToOneField(HomeWork, null=True, blank=True)
```

You don't want `primary_key=True` for the `after_homework` - that would make the `after_homework` the primary key field of the `VideoGamePurchase` model, which doesn't make sense if the field is optional.

It looks like your migrations are messed up because you had `primary_key=True` for the `after_homework` field earlier. The easiest fix would be to start with a fresh database, delete the migrations for that app, then rerun `makemigrations` and `migrate`. This time, the migration will automatically create a primary key field `id` for the `VideoGamePurchase` model.